# Error validating transaction using BLOCKCYPHER

Tags: bitcoin-core, multibit, transaction-verification, broadcast

I recently followed the steps on the answer by **StephenM347** to the following problem:

[Cannot access my bitcoins because my wallet is still synchronising. What can I do to spend them immediately?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/cannot-access-my-bitcoins-because-my-wallet-is-still-synchronising-what-can-i-d?newreg=46bafcf381cd4c1dbf825e81155c7a7c)

However, on the last step (broadcasting my transaction on https://live.blockcypher.com/btc-testnet/pushtx/) I got the error message:

***Error validating transaction: Transaction eddxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx orphaned, missing reference 00350a8xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.***

I am very new to this and all I want is to have my bitcoins on a MultiBit wallet (where I sent the Bitcoin Core bitcoins to).
Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 1):

When a transaction is orphaned it usually means that it is part of an orphaned block. This happens occasionally so there is no reason to panic :)

According to Anonymous in this [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13987/what-happens-when-you-send-a-transaction-that-ends-up-in-an-orphaned-block-is-i), orphaned transactions are not lost and are returned to the memory pool where miners can pick it up again and attempt to confirm it.

In short, as long as the transaction has a high enough fee (which it should have considering it was added to a block already) it should confirm eventually.

You can also keep track of it using this service:

https://mempool.observer/