# What does an orphaned tx look like via rpc?

Tags: json-rpc, chain-reorganization, stale-block

I am testing with a currency forked from Pivx, but I see that bitcoind responds the same way here https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=100824.0 with error code -5

**If I send/receive a tx that then some time after a few confirmations (the block) was to become orphaned or stale; Would I get the same reply from rpc gettransactions as below (where I intentionally typed a non transaction id in) if I were to look for the tx or should it come back with a full tx object?**

```
zdx-cli gettransaction "gyyyyf"
error: {"code":-5,"message":"Invalid or non-wallet transaction id"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases here:

- Block with the tx became orphaned and the transaction is still valid. In this case it [is returned to the mempool](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13987/what-happens-when-you-send-a-transaction-that-ends-up-in-an-orphaned-block-is-i). *gettransaction* will return unconfirmed transaction detail
- Another conflicting transaction got confirmed ( having same inputs). In this case existing txid becomes invalid and it is discarded